# Bash if test breaks if at least one single quote in user input

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

If the user input contains a single quote such as in

```
$ echo "Hello my name Foo I'm 18" | ./test.sh
```

It fails with error `syntax error: operand expected (error token is "'")`

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line
do
    str=$line
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#str}; i++))
    do
        if [[ "${str:$i:1}" -gt 4 ]]    <-- fails
        then
            echo 'foo'
        elif [[ "${str:$i:1}" -lt 4 ]]    <--- fails
        then
            echo 'bar'
        else
            echo 'not a number'
        fi
    done    
done
```

How can I make my code work when the user types in an apostrophe/single quote?

Comment: Do you mean "*exactly* one single quote" or "*at least* one single quote"?

Comment: @Jubobs corrected, thanks

Comment: The problem is that `-gt` and `-lt` expect integer arguments, and if the argument is a valid identifier (such as `H`, `e`, etc) it is expanded as a parameter. In most cases, those parameters don't exist and evaluate to 0 (hence the large number of `bar` outputs. `'`, though, isn't a valid parameter name, so you get an error. Why are you trying to compare strings to integers in the first place, though? I think you need to explain what you are trying to accomplish in order to fix it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    str=$line
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#str}; i++)); do
        ch="${str:$i:1}"
        if [[ $ch == [0-9] && $ch -gt 4 ]]; then
            echo 'foo'
        elif [[ $ch == [0-9] && $ch -lt 4 ]]; then
            echo 'bar'
        else
            echo 'not a number'
        fi
    done
done
```

- Use `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`
- Check if character is a digit using `$ch == [0-9]` before using `-gt` or `-lt` operators to avoid **operand expected** error.

Comment: Seems to me like that would provide the wrong result if the input were, for example, `18`. (Also, you can check if `$i` is a number using a simple pattern: `$i != *[!0-9]*`)